# Sql script to use a column from one table and populate another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables Product table and Rate Table.

**Product**

```
ProductId Name
```

**Rate**

```
LevelId Cost ProductId
```

Each Product has 7 Levels and cost for each level is 100, 200.... 700.

I now need a script to take all the product Ids and Populate the Rate table , so that my end output would look like this :

**Rate**

**LevelId      Cost   ProductId**

```
1          100    1  
2          200    1  
3          300    1  
4          400    1  
5          500    1  
6          600    1  
7          700    1  
1          100    2
```

and so on

Currently I insert the first 7 rows manually and then run the below query for every product id

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Rate (LevelID, Cost, ProductId)
    SELECT LevelID, Cost, ProductId FROM dbo.Rate WHERE ProductId = 1
```

Can you direct me on how to fully automate my work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO Rate
 SELECT   bs.level, bs.costs, P.productid
 FROM
     (SELECT 1 as level, 100 as cost
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as level, 200 as cost
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as level, 300 as cost
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as level, 400 as costs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as level, 500 as costs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 as level, 600 as costs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as level, 600 as costs) bs,
   Product P
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 1 as LevelID , 100 as Cost
 UNION ALL
 SELECT LevelID + 1 , Cost + 100 
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE LevelID < 7)
INSERT INTO Rate
SELECT CTE.LevelID, CTE.Cost, Product.ProductID
FROM CTE CROSS JOIN Product
```

A CTE can create a virtual table of data using an algorithm, so there is no need to manually create a table full of predictable data.  A query using six `UNION ALL`s is not so bad, but what about hundreds or thousands or millions?  If you have more than 100 recursions and not more than 32767, you'd need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)` where `n` is the number of loops you need, or if you had more than 32767 loops, you'd need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` and be wary of a infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for reference. I have been meaning to look into this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (levelid INT)

INSERT INTO #temp (levelid) 
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5
UNION ALL  
SELECT 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7

insert into dbo.rate
SELECT levelid, (levelid * 100) AS cost, productid
FROM dbo.Product 
CROSS JOIN #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

I created a temp table with the 7 levels and then used that.  The cross join creates a combination of each level and each product id.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it out there, assuming you have access to the `master..spt_values` table, you could do this little trick:

```
insert into rate
select distinct s.number, s.number * 100, p.productid
from product p 
  join master..spt_values s
     on s.number > 0 and s.number < 8
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b76bc/2)